# Payara 4 JMS - Any way to log when a connection to MQ Server is created or dropped?

Tags: jms, java-ee-6, payara

We currently have issues after connecting a new MQ Server (IBM MQ v9) to our service.

The current expectation is that we have two issues:

1. The connection establishment at MQ-Server takes too much time
2. We assume that on every message send a new physical connection is established instead of using the payara pool

Especially to prove No. 2 - is there any possibility to find out or log every Connection establishment that is done by the Resource Adapter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Application activity trace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=network-application-activity-trace) of IBM MQ.

There is also a [very nice presentation](https://mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2017/MQTC_2017_Activity_Trace.pdf) available to find out more about how to use the Activity Trace.